# (SQL) Selecting from a database based on multiple pairs of pairs

Tags: sql

The problem I've encountered is attempting to select rows from a database where 2 columns in that row align to specific pairs of data. In other words selecting rows from data where `id = 1 AND type = 'news'`. Obviously, if it was 1 simple pair it would be easy, but the issue is we are selecting rows based on hundreds of pairs of data. I feel as if there must be some way to do this query without looping through the pairs and querying each individually. I'm hoping some SQL stackers can provide guidance.

Here's a full code break down:

Let's imagine that I have the following dataset where `history_id` is the primary key. (I simplified the structure a bit regarding the dates for ease of reading.)

```
table: history
history_id  id  type  user_id  date
1           1   news  1        5/1
2           1   news  1        5/1
3           1   photo 1        5/2
4           3   news  1        5/3
5           4   news  1        5/3
6           1   news  1        5/4
7           2   photo 1        5/4
8           2   photo 1        5/5
```

If the user wants to select rows from the database based on a date range we would take a subset of that data:

```
SELECT history_id, id, type, user_id, date
FROM history
WHERE date BETWEEN '5/3' AND '5/5'
```

Which returns the following dataset:

```
history_id  id  type  user_id  date
4           3   news  1        5/3
5           4   news  1        5/3
6           1   news  1        5/4
7           2   photo 1        5/4
8           2   photo 1        5/5
```

Now, using that subset of data I need to determine how many of those entries represent the *first* entry in the database for each type/id pairing. In other words, is row 4 the *first* time in the database that `id: 3`, `type: news` appears? So I use a `with()` `min()` query.

In real code the two lists are programmatically generated from the result sets of our previous query. (Here I spelled them out for ease of reading.)

```
WITH previous AS (
  SELECT history_id, id, type
  FROM history
  WHERE id IN (1,2,3,4) AND type IN ('news','photo')
) SELECT min(history_id) as history_id, id, type
FROM previous
GROUP BY id, type
```

Which returns the following data set:

```
history_id  id  type  user_id  date
1           1   news  1        5/1
2           1   news  1        5/1
3           1   photo 1        5/2
4           3   news  1        5/3
5           4   news  1        5/3
6           1   news  1        5/4
7           2   photo 1        5/4
8           2   photo 1        5/5
```

You'll notice it's the entire original dataset, because we are matching id and type individually in lists, rather than as a collective pairs.

The result I desire is this, but I can't figure out the SQL to get this result:

```
history_id  id  type  user_id  date
1           1   news  1        5/1
4           3   news  1        5/3
5           4   news  1        5/3
7           2   photo 1        5/4
```

Obviously, I could go the route of looping through each pair and querying the database to determine its first result, but that seems an inefficient solution. I figured one of the SQL gurus on this site might be able to spread some wisdom.

In case I'm approaching this situation incorrectly, the gist of the whole routine is that the database stores all creations and edits in the same table. I need to track each user's behavior and determine how many entries in the history table are edits or creations over a specific date range. Therefore I select all `type:id` pairs from the date range based on a `user_id`, and then for each pairing I determine if the user is responsible for the first record that occurs in the database. If first, then "creation" else "edit".

Answer (score 1):

Don't see the need for two queries... DVK got the idea right though:

```
select id, type, MIN(date) as 'min_date'
from history
where date between YOUR_START_DATE and YOUR_END_DATE
group by id, type
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * 
FROM HISTORY,
    (SELECT    MIN(date) 'min_date', id, type
     FROM      history
     WHERE     id IN (1,2,3,4) AND type IN ('news','photo')
     -- AND DATE BETWEEN xxx and YYY
     GROUP BY  id, type) 'min_dates'
WHERE HISTORY.id     = min_dates.id
 AND  HISTORY.type   = min_dates.type
 AND  HISTORY.date   = min_dates.min_date
```

This is not tested as I don't have DB access at the moment, sorry

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
      h1.history_id,
      h1.id,
      h1.type,
      h1.user_id,
      h1.date
   FROM 
      ( select 
              h2.id, 
              MIN( h2.history_id ) minHistory 
           from 
              history h2
           group by
              h2.id ) ByType,
       history h1
   where 
      ByType.MinHistory = h1.History_ID
```

This will query the entire system wide, regardless of dates.  However, you can your your WHERE criteria on the inner query "from History h2" to limit date range or id types or type descriptions.

Since the inner query will be done first, and obviously have less records, that will be used as the primary to join the FULL history table.  But since its only based on the single History ID record, only that critical record being "First" will be returned as you are hoping to get.